# display all patches/packages installed in the last month

Tags: awk, sed, grep, rpm, date

I would like display all the installed packages of last month with the `rpm -qa --last` command which outputs in this format:

```
libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64                    Tue 01 Nov 2016 12:55:21 PM CET
```

In my script `lastmonth=$(date --date='1 month ago')` is the date from where I want to start displaying the entries. I tried using grep, sed and awk but so far with no results. This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
now = date
lastmonth=$(date --date='1 month ago')
echo $lastmonth

rpm -qa --last |awk '$1>=from&&$1<=to' from=$lastmonth to=$now
```

I didn't do much with `sed (rpm -qa --last |sed -n '/$lastmonth/,/$now/p')`

but this error comes up: `` awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `Feb' for reading (No such file or directory) ``

Comment: If you want to use your variables in scripts, use `"` instead of `'`. Otherwise the variables will not get expanded. But beware of spaces in the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command gives, your requested results

```
rpm -qa --last | grep -w "$(date --date='1 month ago' +'%b %Y')"
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, I'm curious as to how the --date='1 month ago' just seems to work

Comment: date has a syntax to get the previous month, year, date detail and even the detail as per our requirement like 5 years ago, 2 years ago. 2 months ago. Lot more can be done with date which can't be pasted in this comment field :-).

Answer (score 0):

I can't make the script for you.But I can help you in such a way that you can make the script by yourself.
After the installation,below path contains the installation file.
Use below commands,

`cd /usr/local/bin`

`ll`

or

`cd /usr/lib/`

`ll`

For date,you can use below commands

`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "last month"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your variables:

```
rpm -qa --last |awk '$1>=from&&$1<=to' from="$lastmonth" to="$now"
```